# poll() and read() "resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: c, linux, pipe, polling

I have a problem about `read()` with "resource temporarily unavailable".
I'm using PIPE as a IPC between threads.

In my program, reading thread checks if PIPE has a data using `poll()`, and then `read()` from PIPE.
But, sometimes `read()` returns -1 with following error.

> resource temporarily unavailable

I have no idea why `read()` return error after `poll()` check.

Comment: Are you sure you're never trying to read when `poll` *didn't* say it was readable? And you're not calling `read` twice or more after `poll` says it's readable? (In either of those cases, it might not be readable)

Comment: This is in itself not a problem. When you get this particular error, it means there's no data at this point. So just act accordingly, and wait for data to arrive (e.g. go back to your poll() and wait for it to notify you of data that you can read() )

Answer (score 4):

you might have set the pipe fd to non blocking mode O_NONBLOCK and when read happens on empty file, it will return EAGAIN.